# mongoDB select sub-array

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to select a sub-array for a list of restaurants.

For example, I have one object which has:

- address: which has a subarray of 4 elements which are : street number, telephone, mail and city
- restaurant_name

Now I want to project only address, street number and restaurant_name. How is this possible? I have tried it with this:

```
db.restavracije.find({}, {address:1{street_number:1}, restaurant_name:1})
```

but it doesn't work, and if I leave `address:1` without the `{street_number:1}`, then it returns all of the addresses' attributes which are: strret number, telephone mail and city.

The things which I want to project are:

- address

  - street number (only 1 attribute out of all 4)
- restaurant name

Comment: can you post a sample record?

Comment: what do you mean?